# How to add dropdown in OnClick editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a way to add a dropdown box to the OnClick editor in the inspector (circled in the image below)

[image: Dropdown here]

I would like the dropdown to be populated by a custom enum.

Is this possible at all or do I need to find another way to do this?

Goal:
Have an enum of audio clips and be able to assign a clip to a button all from the inspector without having to go into the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity UI Onclick inspector with Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003811/unity-ui-onclick-inspector-with-enumeration)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how the editor and C# script interface with each other I would simply use:

```
public static bool DropdownButton(GUIContent content, FocusType focusType, params GUILayoutOption[] options);
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.DropdownButton.html

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not supported and is not that easy to code yourself. It would require some deep hacks into the source code of `UnityEventDrawer` and `UnityEventBase` and kind of reproducing the entire `UnityEventDrawer` ([source is avalable though ...](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/UnityEventDrawer.cs))

---

However there is a very simple workaround (at least if every `Button` shall playback exactly one sound)

Have a separate component like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class PlayASound : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference via inspector
    [SerializeField] private AudioSelector _audioSelector;

    // your enum type here
    public AudioMessageType MessageType;

    public void Play()
    {
        _audioSelector.PublishAudioMesssage(MessageType);
    }

    private Button _button;

    private void Awake()
    {
         _button = GetComponent<Button>();

        if (!_button)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No Button found on this GameObject!", this);
            return;
        }

        _button.onClick.AddListener(Play);
    }

    // Just to to be sure
    // usually the button should be destroyed along with this component
    // anyway ... but you never know ;)
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _button.onClick.RemoveListener(Play);
    }
}
```

attach it to the **same** GameObject as the `Button` component, select the according enum value there, done. The Listener to `onClick` will not appear in the Inspector but will be added on runtime.

If you prefer to add it manually (I sometimes prefer to have it visible) then simply remove the `Awake` and `OnDestroy` and rather drag it in manually as usual and select the `Play` method.